# Description text slips below instead of above textfield

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm doing a responsive layout. I have this simple div:

```html
<div>
  <input type="password" class="textfields" name="confirmpass">
  <span class="jconfirmpass">confirm password</span>
</div>
```

When I reduce the browser window I want the  description text above textfield. Currently, it wraps under.

Comment: can you just put the span above input?

Comment: no because I want text description after textfield in desktop mode

Comment: what are you using for responsive site? bootstrap or your own code?

Comment: my own code not bootstrap